# Open SharePoint Word document in windows application

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to open an existing Word document that is actually located in a SharePoint library in a Windows application (WinForms).

If I open the document using Internet Explorer, the document is in readonly but I have a "Edit Document" button in Word application that I can use to be able to save my document (remove the read-only).

I've tried the following in my Windows application to open a SharePoint document:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://.../MyFile.docx");
```

This is actually opening my document in Word but I have a problem. If I open my document using this method, the document opened is in readonly and I do not see the "Edit Document" button... How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: I think this is just a win app issue and the file in sharepoint library has nothing to do with if the user who runs the app has the appropriate privileges

Comment: are you able to use this line of code to open, say a word document from a sharepoint location? for example System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("winword.exe"
"https:\\sharepoint.com\documentlibrary\Winword.exe", username, password, domain)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try clicking on the "Save As..." option in Word in order to get an editable version of the document?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to start ms word (winword.exe) as the program with an argument to open the document.

Take a look at the KB article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565

Comment: does this work for anyone? i tried and couldn't get the code to work properly